# Node.JS/Fetch: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors

I receive the error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header" even though my server-side code looks like this:

```
const express = require('express'); //make express available
const app = express(); //invoke express
const multer  = require('multer') //use multer to upload blob data
const upload = multer(); // set multer to be the upload variable (just like express, see above ( include it, then use it/set it up))
const fs = require('fs'); //use the file system so we can save files

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
  next();
});

app.post('/upload', upload.single('data'), function (req, res, next) {

  console.log(req.file_name); // see what got uploaded


  fs.writeFileSync(req.file_name, Buffer.from(new Uint8Array(req.data))); // write the blob to the server as a file
  res.sendStatus(200); //send back that everything went ok

})

//serve out any static files in our public HTML folder
// app.use(express.static('public'))

//makes the app listen for requests on port 3000
app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("app listening on port 3000!")
})
```

Here is the client-side code that yields the error:

```
     fetch(`https://www.eartrainer.app/upload/`, 
  { method: "POST",  body: formdata, // with our form data packaged above
  headers: new Headers({ 'enctype': 'multipart/form-data',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Origin'}) 
}).then(response => {
      if (response.ok) return response;
      else throw Error(`Server returned ${response.status}: ${response.statusText}`);
  }).then(response => console.log(response.text()))
  .catch(err => {
      alert(err);
  });
```

Please note, the server is in app.js located here at https://www.example.com/upload/

Comment: Have you tried specifying cors in the fetch call? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Just tried that and I get the same error. See update.

Comment: Are your express served behind nginx or something?

Comment: Not sure/don't think so?

Comment: I was able to achieve this with php on the server side. The server-side is more or less the same.

Comment: (I still want to achieve it with node though!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) module. Install though npm...

```sh
$ npm i cors
```

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

Check out [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) for more information

Comment: I tried that and I have the same error still. I wonder if something is setup wrong on my server setup? To be clear, the server-side code sits in example.com/upload/app.js, with app.js being the app main file. I've tried app.post('/upload', app.post('/', app.post('./' and none work.